# creating a new thread in c for linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer, udp

```
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int acceptSocket;
struct sockaddr_in addr, server, client;
char buf[100];
long rc,sentbytes;
socklen_t len;
int port = 18227


int CreateSocket()
{


     if(rc!=0)

       {

         printf("socket failure code: %ld\n",rc);

         return 1;

       }

       else

       {

         printf("socket started!\n");

       }

       // Socket creation for UDP

       acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

       if(acceptSocket==-1)

       {

         printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");

         return 1;

       }

       else

       {

         printf("Socket started!\n");

       }

     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

     addr.sin_family=AF_INET;

     addr.sin_port=htons(port);

     addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(INADDR_ANY);

     rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));

     if(rc== -1)

     {

       printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n");

       return 1;

     }

     else

     {

       printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);

     }


     while(rc!=-1)
         {

         len =sizeof(server);

         rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &server, &len);
         if(rc==0)
         {
           printf("Server has no connection..\n");
           break;
         }
         if(rc==-1)
         {
             printf("something went wrong with data %s", strerror(errno));
           break;
         }
     //for recieving the data
          XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );


            makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
                makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
                makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms
          }




       close(acceptSocket);



       return 0;

     }



int main()
{

     Xcp_Initialize();
     CreateSocket();
     return 0;
}
```

I created a server side program for receiving data from the client and sending the response back to the client.There are some api whose definition is not shown above. If i run the above program then there is some blocking while recieving the data. Someone suggested to create a new thread from while(rc != -1) to solve the problem. So could some one help me to do this ??

now i created a thread but it showing some error. 
.....
...

```
 else
     {
         void *thread1()
         {
     while(rc!=-1)
         {


         rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);
         if(rc==0)
```

.....
.
.

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
     Xcp_Initialize();
     CreateSocket();

     pthread_create (&tid, NULL, thread1, NULL);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `thread1` looks like a [nested function](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) -using a GCC extension to the C language. It should be an ordinary, toplevel, function. Compile with `gcc -Wall -pedantic -g -std=c99`

Answer (score 3):

The call you're looking for is `pthread_create()`. You should go away and read up on pthreads (such as [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)), then attempt to to implement something.

*Then,* when you have a question it won't take an entire book to answer, come back and ask it :-)

Comment: I know that should use pthread_create but how to put the while(rc != -1) within the thread name. So could you please give me an example. I have to submit my project by evening!! so could you lease help me.

Comment: You don't put any statements inside a *name*. You should have a function `void* my_thread_work(void*)` and pass it to `pthread_create`. If you don't understand now the basics of pthreads you should accept to fail your homework tomorrow.

Comment: @user3354789. I can only offer the following: (1) Despite what some people say, you can't learn pthreads in a day. (2) lack of planning on your part does not constitute an emergency on ours, so it makes no difference to us what your deadlines are. (3) Absorb this as a valuable lesson. Start your homework earlier. Sorry if that sounds brutal, it's not my intent but, if you're only just thinking about figuring this out on the day it's due, you're already too late.

Comment: how to add the code from while(rc != -1) inside the my_thread_work() ??

Comment: Read a good C programming book. And give up this homework. Your lack of knowledge (and work) on C and pthreads is too big to be caught up in a dozen of hours.

Comment: I edite my code and added code for creating a thread but it showing errors like : /src/MAIN.c:368:31: error: 'thread1' undeclared (first use in this function)
../src/MAIN.c:368:31: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: I'm sorry. You lack basic knowledge about C programming and about pthreads. **Give up** your homework. Next year, take more time to learn stuff and do homework. Don't expect to be able to do that homework in a few hours (without cheating).